# How to create a persistent javascript where it updates when content is constantly updated via ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a webpage that updates via ajax. It loads updated news feeds every 1 minute. What I want to do is create a javascript that detects the incoming date field and put a strong tag around it. Here's a sample of the html that gets feed through:

```
<div class="results">
  <div class="article">
    <div class="date">jan 8, 2013</div>
    <p>Some content here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <div class="date">feb 8, 2013</div>
    <p>Some content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can write the basic javascript that updates it, but it only fires once. How do I go about making javascript detect if there is anything changed in the "results" element and act accordingly.

Comment: Well if you have control over the code that updates the DOM that should be pretty straight forward, no? I do not see the issue here. And what do you mean by "detects the incoming date field"? If you want to style the date, you can just add a CSS rule... `.date { font-weight: bold; }`

Comment: its just an example. i want to customize a site which I do have control of the code. I basically want to write a javascript code that detects TODAY's date and then put a strong tag on it. but the DOM constantly updates since its loaded via ajax.

Comment: You should show your ajax call and your DOM updating code if you want your question to be answered.

Comment: As plalx says, it looks like its a matter of modifying the callback for the ajax call

Comment: @duckx Updated my answer.

Comment: I also think you should modify the code where AJAX call is ended, or HTML is inserted to check the HTML for date and apply whatever you want. Maybe this question is just and example and you have planned other things which rely on subtree modification events, though there is always a simpler solution. These events are not compatible with older browsers and/or not reliable.

Comment: Why not to simply use css like `.results .article .date {font-weight: bold;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you attach a listener to the Ajax (either *.complete()* or *.ajaxStop()*), then get all dates and compare them to today`s date. If they match make the date bold.
Something like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    var today = new Date();

    $.each( $('.article .date'), function( i, el ){
        var el_text = el.text();
        if(el_text == today.toLocaleFormat('%b %d, %Y')) {
            el.html('<b>' + el_text + '</b>');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JQuery (you should tag your question with the `jquery` tag), then you want a solution like this using [**`$.ajaxComplete`**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/). If you're using some other framework, there are other ways to go about this similarly.

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(".results .date").each(function() {
    var strong = $('<strong>').text($(this).text());
    $(this).empty().append(strong);
  });
});

// for this test, only to demonstrate, manually trigger an ajax complete event
function test() {
  $(document).trigger('ajaxComplete');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">
  <div class="article">
    <div class="date">jan 8, 2013</div>
    <p>Some content here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <div class="date">feb 8, 2013</div>
    <p>Some content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
Test: <button onclick="test()">Trigger JQuery Ajax Complete Event</button>
```

The only way to detect a change in the results is to either **A)** make an assumption based on the result saying that it promises it's new or **B)** comparing it to the previous version. You can use [**`$.ajaxSend`**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/) to stash the changes for method **B**.

If you're going by method **A**, you could just keep track of the max date, and do something only if the date is greater, then update the max date with that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Ajax success callback then you can use DOMSubtreeModified event. e.g

```
$('div.results').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {

        alert('changed');
 });
```

This will be fired when content of div.result changes. int this event you will be able to do whatever manipulation you want with div.date

Comment: This has been deprecated in place of Mutation Observers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events